# Trying to get_adjacent_post - in same category not working

Tags: next-post-link

this is my first time here.
I need my previous and next posts to show only posts on the same category. But I don't know how to do it.

This is the code in my template (called Valenti) it is in a file called core.php

```php
/*********************
 CLEAN NEXT/PREVIOUS LINKS
*********************/

if ( ! function_exists( 'cb_previous_next_links' ) ) {
    function cb_previous_next_links() {

          $cb_previous = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
          $cb_next = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );
          if ( ( $cb_next != NULL ) || ( $cb_previous != NULL ) ) {

              $cb_empty = '<div class="cb-empty">' . __("x", "cubell").'</div>';

              echo'<div id="cb-previous-next-links" class="cb-post-footer-block clearfix">';

              if ( $cb_previous != NULL ) {

                         echo '<div id="cb-previous-link"><a href="' . get_permalink($cb_previous) . '"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></a>';
                         previous_post_link('%link');
                         echo '</div>';

              } else {
                  echo $cb_empty;
              }
               if ( $cb_next != NULL ) {
                         echo '<div id="cb-next-link"><a href="' . get_permalink($cb_next) . '"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>';
                         next_post_link('%link');
                         echo '</div>';

              } else {
                  echo $cb_empty;
              }

              echo '</div>';
           }
    }
}
```

I have been  trying many things, but none is working, it is not showing posts on the same category.

tryied doing this, but it is not working and don't know why

```
 $cb_previous = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'category' );
  $cb_next = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'category' );
```

what can I do? Not a coder, so I need you to explain in details or with examples if I have to add a snippet in functions or to modify the code above.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community! As it stands, we don't have enough information to answer the question. This just defines a function - are you calling that function in a template somewhere? If so, which? What are the symptoms of it "not working" - do the links or markup surrounding the links print? Please [file an edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/405231/edit) to add additional information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! I have just edited the post. Hope it is more clear now, and you can help me.